# Send single IP address to a specific page using mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, centos5, apache-2.2

Apache on our CentOS VDS is being monitored by the hosting company (due to previous issues when on a shared hosting server). The site they are monitoring is an on-line store and this has the rather unfortunate side effect of making it appear as if there are numerous visitors on-line at any given moment. It also fills the store's logs with irrelevant entries. None of this is critical but I'd like to eliminate these issues.

I am trying to use mod_rewrite commands in the .htaccess file to redirect that one IP address to a dummy page rather than letting it enter the store. Googling produces many examples but they are all for requests for a specific page, whereas in my case no page is being requested.

Here is what I've ended up with (192.168.0.23 being my test client) but it just results in a loop:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 192\.168\.0\.23
RewriteRule .* /monitor.html [R=301,L]
```

This example is being tested on my dev server using wget (using either the IP address or the domain name) and results in this:

```
H:\>wget http://192.168.0.18
--2011-09-26 09:01:07--  http://192.168.0.18/monitor.html
Connecting to 192.168.0.18:80... connected.
```

the response is repeated until

```
--2011-09-26 09:01:07--  http://192.168.0.18/monitor.html
Connecting to 192.168.0.18:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://192.168.0.18/monitor.html [following]
20 redirections exceeded.
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible using mod_rewrite or should I tackle this some other way?

tl;dr:

- I need to redirect any request from a specific IP address to a dummy page
- The response must come from the web server, as that is what is being monitored

**Edit**

Here is the content of rewrite_log after performing another `wget http://192.168.0.18`

```
192.168.0.23 - - [21/Sep/2011:21:27:07 +1000] [192.168.0.18/sid#937eab8][rid#95330f8/initial] (2) [perdir /path/to/website/files/] explicitly forcing redirect with http://192.168.0.18/monitor.html
192.168.0.23 - - [21/Sep/2011:21:27:07 +1000] [192.168.0.18/sid#937eab8][rid#95330f8/initial] (1) [perdir /path/to/website/files/] escaping http://192.168.0.18/monitor.html for redirect
192.168.0.23 - - [21/Sep/2011:21:27:07 +1000] [192.168.0.18/sid#937eab8][rid#95330f8/initial] (1) [perdir /path/to/website/files/] redirect to http://192.168.0.18/monitor.html [REDIRECT/301]
192.168.0.23 - - [21/Sep/2011:21:27:07 +1000] [192.168.0.18/sid#937eab8][rid#9535100/initial] (3) [perdir /path/to/website/files/] strip per-dir prefix: /path/to/website/files/monitor.html -> monitor.html
192.168.0.23 - - [21/Sep/2011:21:27:07 +1000] [192.168.0.18/sid#937eab8][rid#9535100/initial] (3) [perdir /path/to/website/files/] applying pattern '^/monitor\.html$' to uri 'monitor.html'
192.168.0.23 - - [21/Sep/2011:21:27:07 +1000] [192.168.0.18/sid#937eab8][rid#9535100/initial] (4) [perdir /path/to/website/files/] RewriteCond: input='192.168.0.23' pattern='192\.168\.0\.23' => matched
192.168.0.23 - - [21/Sep/2011:21:27:07 +1000] [192.168.0.18/sid#937eab8][rid#9535100/initial] (2) [perdir /path/to/website/files/] rewrite 'monitor.html' -> '/monitor.html'
192.168.0.23 - - [21/Sep/2011:21:27:07 +1000] [192.168.0.18/sid#937eab8][rid#9535100/initial] (2) [perdir /path/to/website/files/] explicitly forcing redirect with http://192.168.0.18/monitor.html
192.168.0.23 - - [21/Sep/2011:21:27:07 +1000] [192.168.0.18/sid#937eab8][rid#9535100/initial] (1) [perdir /path/to/website/files/] escaping http://192.168.0.18/monitor.html for redirect
192.168.0.23 - - [21/Sep/2011:21:27:07 +1000] [192.168.0.18/sid#937eab8][rid#9535100/initial] (1) [perdir /path/to/website/files/] redirect to http://192.168.0.18/monitor.html [REDIRECT/301]
```

Hopfuly someone can make sense of it. As far as I can tell it thinks `monitor.html` <> `monitor.html`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} 192\.168\.0\.23
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/monitor\.html$
RewriteRule $ /monitor.html [R=301,L]
```

~

Comment: Bingo! (filler to satisfy the 15 character minimum)

Comment: Oops. I was too quick on the trigger. The redirect certainly works but it's redirecting every request to /monitor.html

Comment: Double oops. I tested by removing the "3" from the address but of course 192\.168\.0\.2 still matches 192.168.0.23. I need to slow down and concentrate more. :(

Comment: :( Something to do with the Condition. Let me double check.

Comment: `^192\.168\.0\.2$`

Comment: For what it's worth, it's not good for performance to apply more expressions to a request than needed.  Using the `RewriteRule` for matching the request instead of a separate `RewriteCond` works just fine (if you have the prefix set right for the context, that is).

Comment: Also, REMOTE_ADDR is the most appropriate than REMOTE_HOST, right?

Comment: Its weird that both works for me. At-least I tested it from two servers :(

Comment: @SparX Yeah, I agree; `REMOTE_HOST` may be a DNS name from a reverse lookup in some cases.

Comment: I'd remove the $ from the document.  Otherwise it matches only: /monitor.html but not /monitor.html&key=value or anything else. just my two bits.

Answer (score 2):

Just don't redirect when the requested page is the monitoring page:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^192\.168\.0\.23$
RewriteRule !^monitor\.html$ /monitor.html [R=301,L]
```

(edited for `.htaccess` context and exact host IP matching)

Comment: I don't understand why but I'm still getting a redirection look. Sure looks like it should work.

Comment: Try using `REMOTE_ADDR` instead of `REMOTE_HOST`.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers I've got nothing.  Maybe set a `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel 9`, see if that gives us anything interesting?

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers Oh, it's in `.htaccess`, missed that.  Just drop the `/` from the match.  `RewriteRule !^monitor\.html$ /monitor.html [R=301,L]`